# In WPF, can I handle a XAML exception? Like when an Image tries to load something with zero bytes?

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, exception

I am getting a "No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found" error when  my XAML containing:

```
   <Image x:Name="ProcessImage" Grid.Row="0"  Stretch="Uniform">
       <Image.Source>
           <BitmapImage CacheOption="OnLoad" UriSource="{Binding FilePath}"/>
       </Image.Source>
   </Image>
```

because the FilePath points to an image with zero bytes.  How can I just have it show nothing without breaking everything?

Comment: If returns null there's TargetNullValue, or a Converter etc. I forget what zero bytes returns exactly but maybe even a DataTrigger. You just want to grab that value and if it matches that condition either load it with a place holder or could even collapse it all together.

Comment: If I used a converter on the UriSource, what would I return when I noticed it pointed to an empty file?  I tried to use a visibility convertr on the Image itself, but it seems that the image.source inner XAML still executed and threw an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't think that this situation can be handled in an elegant way, but, basically, you've got two proper options and a hack to try:

- Use a `FallbackValue` in the binding declaration: this nice option allows you to specify an alternative, in case the binding is not successfull (well, literally, in case the `Path` or `ValueConverter` is incorrect).

An example; In this case, the image won't show anything, and **there will be no error**, since the `UriSource` is set correctly:

```
<BitmapImage CacheOption="OnLoad" UriSource='{Binding FilePath, FallbackValue=""}'/>
```

- Use `PriorityBinding`. This lets you set multiple bindings in a **prioritised** top-down order.

An example:

```
<BitmapImage CacheOption='OnLoad'>
    <BitmapImage.UriSource>
        <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path='FilePath' />
            <Binding Path='Whatever1' />
            <Binding Path='Whatever2' />
        </PriorityBinding>
    </BitmapImage.UriSource>
</BitmapImage>
```

In this case, the resolving logic would be `FilePath` -> `Whatever1` -> `Whatever2`.

- And, finally, you may use a **hack**: Put your exception handling logic into a custom `ValueConverter` and return the bitmap data if the image is correct, or, in case something goes wrong, an image placeholder (maybe a funny HTTP 404 error image).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this; If the image is Null/Empty replace with a emptyImage wich you know you have.

```
<Image x:Name="ProcessImage" Grid.Row="0"  Stretch="Uniform">
<Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding FilePath}" /> 
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilePath}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="~/images/noImg.jpg"  />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make it show nothing when the file is empty or even does not exist, you may simply bind the `Image.Source` property directly instead of explictly creating a `BitmapImage`:

```
<Image x:Name="ProcessImage" Source="{Binding FilePath}" />
```

WPF's built-in type conversion will automatically create a `BitmapFrame` from the path string or Uri.